# Photoshopで自由変形時の基準点をアクションで自動選定させたい

Tags: photoshop

Photoshopで画像の一部を自由変形させる作業を行っています。
この際、自由変形を開始する時点で、右端や左端などの任意の点に基準点を選択させ、画像の伸縮作業を行いたいのですが、うまくアクションに取り込めません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

アクションの録画では、自由変形の基準点を変更し、伸縮率などを設定した結果のスクリプトは作成できます。ただ、自分が行う作業では、それぞれの画像に対する変形度合いが異なっていますので、画像の基準点のみ自動選択し、変形は手動でその都度調整したいと考えております。

自由変形させる際に、基準点位置をセンター以外のポイントにセットするようなスクリプトは記述できるでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebookに共有したところ、下記の回答をいただきました。

録画後に「ウィンドウ＞アクション」で録画したアクションを開いてみて「変形」の項目の左側の四角をクリックするとダイアログモードになります。これでこのアクションを実行すると、自由変形のところだけ手動になるので、右側をドラッグすると左端を基準に変形、左側をドラッグすると右端を基準に変形します。バーの○をクリックすると、その後のアクションは自動で進みます。

上記の内容で解決いたしました。
ありがとうございます。